# Создать генератор букв. Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно заполнить список `arr` буквами по такому алгоритму:

1. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
2. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab'
3. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac'

и так далее

26. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba'
27. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb'
28. 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabc'

и так далее со всем английским алфавитом
Мне нужно пополнять его до того как память не заполниться

Пожалуйста подскажите решение как заполнить список `arr` такими буквами

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: «и так далее» до какого момента? Если до 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' — осознаёте ли вы, что это займёт не менее 882051251858352083253842461 гигабайт памяти?

Comment: @andreymal да, осознаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ideone.com/t229xs

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 
i = 0

for x in (b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z for b in a for c in a for d in a for e in a for f in a for g in a for h in a for i in a for j in a for k in a for l in a for m in a for n in a for o in a for p in a for q in a for r in a for s in a for t in a for u in a for v in a for w in a for x in a for y in a for z in a):
  print(x)
  i += 1
  if i == 100: break
```

Comment: Красиво, хотя и длинно. Я так до коца и не понял, как это работает...

Comment: @Глеб, обычный генератор из 25 вложенных циклов))) Не особо оптимально (все конкатенации повторяются на каждой итерации), но для программы, работающей 10**18 лет, замедление в 26 раз как-то некритично)))

Answer (score 6):

```
import string
import itertools

for p in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=25):
    print(''.join(p))
```

> ```
> $ python product.py | head -30
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaae
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaag
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaai
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaj
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaak
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaam
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaao
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaq
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaar
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaau
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaav
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaw
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaba
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabc
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabd
> ```